# Show that $\ M$ =sup $\ E$ iff for all $\varepsilon \gt$ 0 there is an $\ x$ in $\ E$ such that $\ M$ $\ - \varepsilon \lt x \le M$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum, epsilon-delta

Let *E* be a bounded set and *M* be an upper bound for *E*. Show that *M*=sup *E* iff for all $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there is an *x* in *E* such that $\ M - \varepsilon \lt x \le M$

so I know we have to prove it both ways, so we must prove:

for the forwards direction:
$\ M = $ sup *E* $\ \Rightarrow \forall$ $\varepsilon \gt 0$ $\exists$ $\ x \in E \ni M - \varepsilon \lt x \le M$

and for the backwards direction:
$ \forall$ $\varepsilon \gt 0$ $\exists$ $\ x \in E \ni M - \varepsilon \lt x \le M$ $\Rightarrow$ *M* = sup *E*

I figured for the forward direction that you could suppose *x* $\gt$ *M* which would imply that there is an $\ m \in \mathbb{R} \ni$ *m* $\lt$ *M* and also an upper bound for *E* but I'm not sure where that gets me in regards to proving the statement..

I was playing around with the backwards direction and this is what i came up with:

suppose $\ M \neq$ sup *E*, then $\ \exists \varepsilon \gt 0 \ni \forall x \in E$, $\ M - \varepsilon \ge x \gt M $

$\Rightarrow$ *M* is in *E* and there are elements of *E* that are greater than *M*. This means *M* could not be an upper bound for *E* which contradicts what we are given about *M* (that *M* *is* an upper bound for *E*).
Thus our assumption is false and therefore *M* = sup *E*.

I guess I'm looking for verification of the backwards direction of my proof and help in proving the forward direction of the statement (and the backwards direction if I am wrong).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I figured for the forward direction that you could suppose x > M "  That ... wont work.  The statement is that there *exists* an $x$ nothing about what it is.  So supposing that $x > M$ won't do anything.  Afterall.   There are an *INFINITE* number of $x > M$ so assume $x> M$ (lets say $x = M + 5$billion) won't prove there *ISN"T* some other $x' < M$.... Analogy: If we want to prove that there is a person who is a doctor.  Assume $x$ is a trombone player, want lead to a contradiction.  That just means $x$ is not a doctor.  But someone *ELSE* could be.

Comment: okay, i see... that makes sense. i'll think about it some more. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are defining $\sup E$ as the least upper bound of $E$.

Suppose $M=\sup E$. Then, if $\varepsilon>0$, the number $M-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound of $E$, hence there exists $x\in E$ such that $M-\varepsilon<x$. The fact that $x\le M$ follows from $M$ being an upper bound of $E$.

Suppose the stated condition holds and let $N$ be an upper bound of $E$. We need to prove that $N\ge M$. By way of contradiction, suppose $N<M$. Then $\varepsilon=M-N>0$ and so there exists $x\in E$ with
$$
M-\varepsilon <x\le M
$$
On the other hand $M-\varepsilon=M-(M-N)=N$, so we have $N<x$: a contradiction to $N$ being an upper bound of $E$.

Now compare this argument to yours to see whether your proof is good.

Comment: for the second paragraph ("suppose the stated condition holds....") what stated condition are we talking about? one laid out in the paragraph before or one given in the problem? sorry if this is a dumb question the rest of your proof makes sense that's all i'm confused about

Comment: @pyat The condition “for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $x\in E$ such that $M-\varepsilon<x\le M$”, what else?

Comment: that was it. I really like your proof, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

**hint for farward**

Le $ P,Q $ and $ R$  be the propositions

$$P : M=\sup E$$
$$Q : \forall x\in E \; x\le M$$
$$R : \forall \epsilon>0\; \exists x\in E : \; x>M-\epsilon $$
You want to prove that
$$P \implies Q \wedge R$$

$$P\implies M \text{ is an upperbound of } E$$
$$\implies \forall x\in E \; x\le M$$
Now let us prove that
$$P \implies R$$
by proving the contrapositive

$$\text{ not } R\implies \text{ not } P.$$

$$\text{not } R \implies$$
$$\exists \epsilon>0 : \forall x\in E\; x\le M-\epsilon$$

$$\implies M-\epsilon \text{ is an upperbound of } E$$

$$\implies M-\epsilon \text{ is an upperbound of } E \text{ smaller than } M$$

$$\implies M\ne \sup E$$
done.

Answer (score 1):

The *definition* of $\sup E= k$ is 1) $k$ is an upper bound of $E$ and 2) if $a < k$ than $a$ is not an upper bound.

We are given that $M$ is an upper bound if $E$.

ONE:  $\sup E = M\implies$ for all $\epsilon >0$ then there is an $x\in E$ so that $M-\epsilon < x \le M$.

Pf:  $M=\sup E$.  For all $\epsilon > 0$ then $M - \epsilon < M$. So $M-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $E$.

So $M-\epsilon$ is not $\ge x$ for all $x \in E$ so there must exist an $x \in E$ so that $x > M-\epsilon$.

And as $M$ *is* an upper bound of $E$ we know $M \ge x$.

So $M-\epsilon < x \le M$.

TWO:  If for all $\epsilon >0$ then there is an $x: M-\epsilon < x \le M$ then $M = \sup E$.

Proof:  Fo $M = \sup E$ two thing must happen.  1) $M $ must be an upper bound of $E$.  It is.

2. If $a < M$ then $a$ can not be an upper bound of $E$.

Let $a < M$.  Then if we let $\epsilon = M -a > 0$ then we have that there is an $x \in E$ so that

$a = M -\epsilon < x \le M$.  So $x > a$ and so $a$ is not an upper bound of $M$.

So the second condition holds.  Therefore $M = \sup E$.